# hive table query Error in configuring object

Tags: regex, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive

I'm loading a log file in S3 into Hive running on EMR but I'm getting all NULLs back when viewing the data...

I created the table like this:

```
create external table coglogs (
  HostID string,
ProcessID string,
Time string,
TimeZoneOffset string,
SessionID string,
RequestID string,
SubRequestID string,
StepID string,
Thread string,
Component string,
BuildNumber string,
Level string,
Logger string,
Operation string,
ObjectType string,
ObjectPath string,
Status string,
Message string,
LogData string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "([\d+]\S+[\d+])\t(\d+)\t([\d+]\S+[\d+] [\d+]\S+[\d+])\t(-[\d+])\t([a-zA-Z0-9_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z0-9_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z0-9_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z0-9_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z0-9_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S]*)\t([0-9]*)\t([0-9]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S ]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S ]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S ]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S ]*)\t([a-zA-Z_\S ]*)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s %16$s %17$s %18$s %19$s"
)
location 's3n://infinilog/cogserver_hive.log';
```

and then load the data:

```
load data inpath 's3n://infinilog/cogserver.log' into table coglogs;
```

I checked the regex rubular.com and it seems to be correct but why am i not getting any data back in the hive table?

here is an example line in the log file:

```
101.196.242.160:9300    11329   2016-01-27 18:35:14.132 -5                  http-9300-297   caf 2047    2   Audit.dispatcher.caf    Request         Warning     secure error - found userCapabilities
101.196.242.160:9300    11329   2016-01-27 18:35:14.195 -5  F3820773ADD59754DEAFAFDFA0D2C3F2CDDF715483446C99B16BFA8040D0DDA4    9ss8Csyswh28w8sGC4hhvvMy2hw9d48Cd42y92y8            http-9300-299   CM  6102    3   Audit.Other.cms.CM  QUERY   REPORT  /Public Folders/1A Reporting/PT/Reports/Summary Dashboard   Success
```

EDIT:

so there is data in the table (I see a lot of rows with all column values as "None" though) but when I run something like this:

```
select count(*)
from coglogs
where status = 'Failure'
```

or any query, I get this back:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:42)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:153)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: stringTypeInfo
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe.initialize(RegexSerDe.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:122)
        ... 22 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't match anything in the log file. And, it reduces to this `(\d+\S+\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+\S+\d+[ ]\d+\S+\d+)\t(-\d+)\t(\S*)\t(S*)\t(\S*)\t(\S*)\t(\S*)\t(\S*)\t(\d*)\t(\d*)\t(\S*)\t(\S*)\t([\S ]*)\t([\S ]*)\t([\S ]*)\t([\S ]*)\t([\S ]*)`

Answer (score 0):

In hive you have to use "\" instead of "\" in regex