# Creating Table in Apache Hive with regex returns all NULL values

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I Have many log file *.log and i want to import to Hive Table with below Syntax:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cache_22 ( 
a STRING, 
b STRING, 
c STRING, 
d STRING, 
e STRING, 
f STRING,
g STRING,
h  STRING, 
i STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'input.regex' =  '(\d+\w+\d+)\:.*?\[.*?\]\s(\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)\s\w*\s\d*\s(\d*)\s\d\s\w*\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\:\d*\s(?:-|http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)','output.format.string' = "%1$$s %2$$s %3$$s %4$$s %5$$s %6$$s %7$$s %8$$s %9$$s")';
```

but when i query it bring null values as below :

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

this is my sample for logs:

```
25Oct2016:103130.123456 [1234567a3] 0.522550 1.244476 TCP_PARTIAL_HIT 206 65871 0 GET 10.10.10.199 11.11.11.11:80 
25Oct2016:103130.654321 [1234567e8] 0.144449 0.178851 TCP_MISS 200 7035 0 GET 5.5.5.5 10.20.30.40:80 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668713/getting-null-values-in-hive-create-load-query-with-regex
```

please correct my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Please confirm if this line is part of your input data "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668713/getting-null-values-in-hive-create-load-query-with-regex"

Answer (score 0):

In your case regular expression(`\\s(?:-|http:\\/\\/|www\\.|https:\\/\\/)([^\\/]+)`) seems faulty with the serde you are using. It seems that the serde you are using is unable to compile those part of regular expression and hence it is restricting to fetch the data.

I have tried multiple scenarios and its results are as follow.

**Scenario 1:** Without any modification in Data and regEx

Input data

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/user1/hive_poc/hive3/file1.txt
25Oct2016:103130.123456 [1234567a3] 0.522550 1.244476 TCP_PARTIAL_HIT 206 65871 0 GET 10.10.10.199 11.11.11.11:80
25Oct2016:103130.654321 [1234567e8] 0.144449 0.178851 TCP_MISS 200 7035 0 GET 5.5.5.5 10.20.30.40:80 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668713/getting-null-values-in-hive-create-load-query-with-regex
[user1@server1 ~]$
```

Hive create table statement

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_regex_test3 (
    > a STRING,
    > b STRING,
    > c STRING,
    > d STRING,
    > e STRING,
    > f STRING,
    > g STRING,
    > h STRING,
    > i STRING
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'input.regex' =  '(\\d+\\w+\\d+)\\:.*?\\[.*?\\]\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s\\w*\\s\\d*\\s(\\d*)\\s\\d\\s\\w*\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\:\\d*\\s(?:-|http:\\/\\/|www\\.|https:\\/\\/)([^\\/]+)',
    > 'output.format.string' = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s")
    > LOCATION '/user/user1/hive_poc/hive3/';
OK
Time taken: 0.046 seconds
hive>
```

**Result:** Not getting any data.

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> add jar /home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar;
Added [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar]
hive> select * from tbl_regex_test3;
OK
tbl_regex_test3.a       tbl_regex_test3.b       tbl_regex_test3.c       tbl_regex_test3.d       tbl_regex_test3.e       tbl_regex_test3.f       tbl_regex_test3.g    tbl_regex_test3.h        tbl_regex_test3.i
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.047 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

**Scenario 2:** Removed the faulty regEx only.

Input data

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/user1/hive_poc/hive/file1.txt
25Oct2016:103130.123456 [1234567a3] 0.522550 1.244476 TCP_PARTIAL_HIT 206 65871 0 GET 10.10.10.199 11.11.11.11:80
25Oct2016:103130.654321 [1234567e8] 0.144449 0.178851 TCP_MISS 200 7035 0 GET 5.5.5.5 10.20.30.40:80 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668713/getting-null-values-in-hive-create-load-query-with-regex
[user1@server1 ~]$
```

Hive create table statement

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_regex_test2 (
    > a STRING,
    > b STRING,
    > c STRING,
    > d STRING,
    > e STRING,
    > f STRING,
    > g STRING,
    > h STRING,
    > i STRING
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'input.regex' =  '(\\d+\\w+\\d+)\\:.*?\\[.*?\\]\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s\\w*\\s\\d*\\s(\\d*)\\s\\d\\s\\w*\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\:\\d*',
    > 'output.format.string' = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s")
    > LOCATION '/user/user1/hive_poc/hive';
OK
Time taken: 0.134 seconds
```

**Result:** Getting the data from 1st row only, 2nd row is null since it is not matching with input regEx.

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> add jar /home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar;
Added [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar]
hive> select * from tbl_regex_test2;
OK
tbl_regex_test2.a       tbl_regex_test2.b       tbl_regex_test2.c       tbl_regex_test2.d       tbl_regex_test2.e       tbl_regex_test2.f       tbl_regex_test2.g    tbl_regex_test2.h        tbl_regex_test2.i
25Oct2016       0.522550        1.244476        65871   10.10.10.199    10.10.10.199    11.11.11.11     11.11.11.11     NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.046 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

**Scenario 3:** Removed the URL part from the data and removed the faulty regEx.

Input data

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/user1/hive_poc/hive1/file.log
25Oct2016:103130.123456 [1234567a3] 0.522550 1.244476 TCP_PARTIAL_HIT 206 65871 0 GET 10.10.10.199 11.11.11.11:80
25Oct2016:103130.654321 [1234567e8] 0.144449 0.178851 TCP_MISS 200 7035 0 GET 5.5.5.5 10.20.30.40:80
[user1@server1 ~]$
```

Hive create table statement

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl_regex_test1 (
    > a STRING,
    > b STRING,
    > c STRING,
    > d STRING,
    > e STRING,
    > f STRING,
    > g STRING,
    > h STRING,
    > i STRING
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'input.regex' =  '(\\d+\\w+\\d+)\\:.*?\\[.*?\\]\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s\\w*\\s\\d*\\s(\\d*)\\s\\d\\s\\w*\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\s(((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\\:\\d*',
    > 'output.format.string' = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s")
    > LOCATION '/user/user1/hive_poc/hive1';
OK
Time taken: 0.15 seconds
hive>
```

**Result:** Great!! Its fetching record from both rows.

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> add jar /home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar;
Added [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/user1/hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.2.0.jar]
hive> select * from tbl_regex_test1;
OK
tbl_regex_test1.a       tbl_regex_test1.b       tbl_regex_test1.c       tbl_regex_test1.d       tbl_regex_test1.e       tbl_regex_test1.f       tbl_regex_test1.g    tbl_regex_test1.h        tbl_regex_test1.i
25Oct2016       0.522550        1.244476        65871   10.10.10.199    10.10.10.199    11.11.11.11     11.11.11.11     NULL
25Oct2016       0.144449        0.178851        7035    5.5.5.5 5.5.5.5 10.20.30.40     10.20.30.40     NULL
Time taken: 0.057 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

From the above result I came in conclusion that the regEx you are using is unable to fetch URL  or it is not compatible with this Hive serde.

I again get surprised when I verified that regEx using [online regular expression compiler](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php) and got result from 2nd row. Please see the below Image for more clarification

[image]

Its resultis:
[image]

From the above result I am dangling to decide that it is a serde issue or regular expression issue and will be waiting for some other answer too.

On other hand, we should avoid regular expression technique in hive, because it is tightly coupled with the position of data and can break with small change in input data.